# Using the Apollo GraphQL client for Android

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, android-studio-2.3, graphql-java

I am using from the below sample, but it gets me an error when I add libraries:

[Using the Apollo GraphQL client for Android](http://engineering.dailymotion.com/using-the-apollo-graphql-client-for-android/)

Below is my *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.apollographql.android:gradle-plugin:0.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my *build.gradle* file (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.apollotest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.apollographql.android:api:0.1.0' // the apollo runtime classes needed by auto-generated code
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0' // retrofit2
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0' // rxjava2 to use the Observables stuff
    compile 'com.apollographql.android:converter-pojo:0.1.0' // converts retrofit responses to pojos (ApolloConverterFactory)
}
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'

apollo {
    // This tells the Apollo compiler to generate actual static classes instead of just interfaces (more on that later)
    generateClasses = true
}
```

Get me the below error:

[image]

Comment: It is too late now, but there is *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is "Couldn't find a schema file. Please ensure a valid schema.json file exists in the sourceSet directory".

Use the `apollo-codegen download-schema` command to create this JSON. This takes the URL of the GraphQL endpoint as a parameter, followed by `--output` and the path to where the JSON should be stored. The JSON should go `src/main/graphql/` of your project, and in there into subdirectories representing the Java package that you want your code to go into (e.g., `--output src/main/graphql/com/commonsware/graphql/trips/api/schema.json`).

So, overall, you might have:

```
apollo-codegen download-schema https://graphql-demo.commonsware.com/0.1/graphql --output src/main/graphql/com/commonsware/graphql/trips/api/schema.json
```

Comment: What can I do  ? 'apollo-codegen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @JoJoRoid: `apollo-codegen` is a Node package. Run the **`npm install -g apollo-codegen`** command. This will install `apollo-codegen` "globally", so it is available to any Android project for which you wish to use Apollo-Android. Note, though, that using the `-g` switch for a global install may require superuser privileges (e.g., `sudo`) on your
development machine.

Comment: Get me this error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:installApolloCodegen'.
> Process 'command 'D:\AndroidStudioProject\TestApollo\app\.gradle\nodejs\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\node.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -4048

Comment: @JoJoRoid: Sorry, I do not know what that one means.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using an old version of Apollo. Those warnings have been fixed in the recent stable version.

I suggest you replace

```
classpath 'com.apollographql.android:gradle-plugin:0.1.0'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.0'
```

and get rid of the `generateClasses = true` block and the `converter-pojo` and `apollo-api` dependencies. Those are no longer needed with the latest version.

Run a clean build after that.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for Apollo CLI [v2.17.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo/v/2.17.2) (apollo-android [v1.0.2](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/releases/tag/1.0.2))

Specifically the GitHub API:

```sh
apollo client:download-schema /src/main/graphql/com/graphql/example/schema.json --endpoint https://api.github.com/graphql --header "Authorization: Bearer <github-token>"
```

[Github. Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)